# How to use GETDATE() Function with LIKE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use `GETDATE()` function with LIKE operator in SQL Server?

```
SELECT * FROM  FeeDetails WHERE Txndate
LIKE '%  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107)%'`
```

Can any one give any inputs on this?

Comment: What is the datatype of TxnDate column?

Comment: Have you tried to use the SQL concatenation operator `||` to form the `LIKE` expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the where clause to

```
where Txndate like '%' +   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107) + '%'
```

given that `Txndate` is of type `varchar` otherwise the `LIKE` operator does not make sense